# Typescript: how to exclude optionality based on a boolean value within the same interface?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an interface and I am trying to implement this:

```
export interface Passenger {
       id: number,
       name: string,
       checkedIn: boolean,
       checkedInDate?: Date // <- How to make this optional only if checkedIn = false
}
```

Comment: Is it available in types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare this in an interface. However you could implement this behaviour in a class:

```
export class Passenger {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   checkedInDate?: Date;

   get checkedIn() {
      return this.checkedInDate != null;
  }       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just ignore the value of variable `checkedInDate` when `checkedIn` is true , something like this

```
if(!pessageobj.checkedIn) {
 pessageobj.checkedInDate = new Date();
} else {
pessageobj.checkedInDate =  some default date like min date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
export type Passenger = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    checkedIn: true,
    checkedInDate: Date
} | {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    checkedIn: false
    checkedInDate?: Date // you can just this field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A template parameter can specify the type of `checkedIn` with greater specificity (than just `boolean`). An intersection can then "add" either the optional or required version of `checkedInDate`.

```js
export type Passenger<A extends boolean> = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    checkedIn: A;
} & (A extends false
    ? {
        checkedInDate?: Date;
    }
    : {
        checkedInDate: Date;
    });
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps